# How To Add Order Limit and Stop Levels to Alerts?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have created a pinescript strategy opens a position with the following code:

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop = close - riskLong, limit = takeProfitLong, qty = math.round(probLossLong / (riskLong / close)))
```

I want to add the `stop` and `limit` values to my alerts. I tried this alert body:

```
{
  "symbol": "{{ticker}}",
  "position": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
  "entry_price": "{{strategy.order.price}}",
  "leverage": "{{strategy.order.contracts}}",
  "stop_loss": "{{strategy.order.stop}}",
  "take_profit": "{{strategy.order.limit}}",
  "timestamp": "{{timenow}}"
}
```

The result is:

```
{
  "symbol": "ETHUSDT.P",
  "position": "buy",
  "entry_price": "2070.93",
  "leverage": "29",
  "stop_loss": "{{strategy.order.stop}}",
  "take_profit": "{{strategy.order.limit}}",
  "timestamp": "2023-11-25T12:00:01Z"
}
```

So the I cannot access the `stop` and `limit` like the `price` or `action`. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. PineScript doesn't support getting the stop and limit values as default. However, you can set custom values using the plot function. Each plotted line can be accessed using `plot_n` format. Where `n` is the index of the plot, starting from 0 up until 19. If there's more than 20 plots, you cannot access their values on alerts if you cannot rearrenge them.

```
var float stopLossLevelGlobal = na 
var float takeProfitLevelGlobal = na

if long
   takeProfitLevelGlobal := x
   takeProfitLevelGlobal := y
if short
   takeProfitLevelGlobal := x
   takeProfitLevelGlobal := y


plot(stopLossLevelGlobal, title="Stop Loss Level", color=color.red)
plot(takeProfitLevelGlobal, title="Take Profit Level", color=color.green)
```

Corrected alert body:

```
{
  "symbol": "{{ticker}}",
  "position": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
  "entry_price": "{{strategy.order.price}}",
  "leverage": "{{strategy.order.contracts}}",
  "stop_loss": "{{plot_0}}",
  "take_profit": "{{plot_1}}",
  "timestamp": "{{timenow}}"
}
```